# .Net Core EF DBContext Migration not working

Tags: entity-framework, migration, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

So, there you are venturing into code-first EF design with Clean Architecture. You have your models in .Core project, db context defined in the .Infra or .Data project. You getting ready to create the migrations and go to the Developer Command Prompt, dial to the infra folder and type out

```
dotnet ef migrations add myDBInit --context MyDbContext --output-dir Migrations
```

And then suddenly you see this error....

*Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...

No static method 'CreateHostBuilder(string[])' was found on class 'Program'.

No application service provider was found.

Finding DbContext classes in the project...

Found DbContext 'MyDBContext'.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'MyDBContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[CaseEscalation.Infra.MyDBContext]' while attempting to activate 'CaseEscalation.Infra.MyDBContext'.

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_4.b__13()*

What do you do!!

Answer (score 3):

Among many different solutions on the internet, the best one is : You need a Temporary DB Context Factory. Especially true (according to few folks) when you are in a clean arch scenario where Program.cs is not part of the project. Paste the below code to the DBContext and this will tell the command prompt how to handle this context!! Migrations will go through now.

```
public class TemporaryDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDBContext>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public TemporaryDbContextFactory() { }
    public TemporaryDbContextFactory(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public MyDBContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDBContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("server=myserver;database=mydatabase;user=myuser;password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Connect Timeout=180",
        optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(MyDBContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));
        return new MyDBContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of all things out there, this worked!

Comment: And it works. For MySQL use "builder.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString))" and that is all.